# How To disable or banishing html element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about disabling or removing HTML elements.

I have 3 groups of select. First group (1,2,3), second group (a,b,c) third group (4,5,6). Here is the logic:

1. If i select (1) on first group, it will make (b and c) option on second group dissapear and (4,5) dissapear
2. If i select (2) on first group, it will make (a) option on second group dissapear and (6) on third group is disabled.
3. If i select (3) on first group, it will make all the option of second group disabled, not dissapear and make (5,6) dissapear.

Can anyone give me a little example of code that needed to do that, or at least to disabled and dissapear HTML element by click event or select event.

Comment: What you have tried up to now??

Comment: Sorry Sarjan.I Already Search Google.But im not getting help.I want to make it interactive like in C++ or C languange.If in c++ or C i can easily set the textbox attribute to false by triggering some event that attached to it.But now its web.I really have no idea.Can u give me little Example.Ill Figure the rest out by myself.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an example on how to do the point two in your list. From this you should be able to adapt a solution for the others. I am assuming the three select boxes has the ids `first`, `second` and `third`.

```
$("#first").change(function() {
    //Reset so that all options are enabled and visible.
    $("option").prop("disabled", false).show();
    //Do different things depending on what value is selected.
    switch($(this).val())
    {
        case "1":
            //Implement some code here.
            break;
        case "2":
            //Hide a option on the second select.
            $("#second option[value=a]").hide();
            //Disable 6 option on third select.
            $("#third option[value=6]").prop("disabled", true);
            break;
        case "3":
            //Implement some code here.
            break;
    }
});
```

Please note that this code relies on the `value` attributes being explicitly set for the options. You could also select the options based on their position in the list, for example `#third option:eq(2)` for the third option in the third list.

You might also want to add some logic so that if a option is selected when it is deleted or disabled, an other option gets selected instead.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cta4cpa3/)

Comment: Thx For the Answer.Im new On Web programming.But I get The logic.Thx Anders. :D

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and a super simple example is like this:

```
<div class="hideMe"> 
some stuff
</div>
```

and then in your script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.hideMe').click(function() {
          //Do some stuff here 
     });

});
```

Comment: Nice.Its Worked.Voted! :D